# If $p$ is a prime, $p > 2$, prove that $1^2 3^2\dots (p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^\frac{p+1}{2}\pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> If $p$ is a prime, $p > 2$, prove that $1^2 3^2\dots (p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^\frac{p+1}{2}\pmod{p}$

I suppose that we could use Wilson's theorem:

$$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$

I am stuck. I would really appreciate help.

Comment: More generally, if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then it is easy to see that the sum is $\equiv 0\pmod p$

Comment: @MarkBennet Sorry, I made a mistake in the title.

Comment: OK, multiply the left by $2^{(p-1)/2}$, distributing the factors $2$ smartly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with $(p-1)!\equiv-1$:
$$1\cdot3\cdots(p-2)\;\;\cdot\;\;2\cdot4\cdots(p-1)=(-1)$$
multiply each even number on the left by $-1$ to obtain
$$1\cdot3\cdots(p-2)\;\;\cdot\;\;(-2)\cdot(-4)\cdots(-p+1)=(-1)\cdot(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$$
then replace each factor $(-2n)$ by $(p-2n)$ to have:
$$1\cdot3\cdots(p-2)\;\;\cdot\;\;(p-2)\cdot(p-4)\cdots3\cdot1=(-1)\cdot(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$$
as desired.